# in a text file that is a list of paths, insert directory immediately before files with certain extension

Tags: replace, sed, awk

I have a list of files in files.txt, a hugely simplified example

```
$FOO%foo\bar\biz.asmx
%FOO%foo\bar\biz.cs
%FOO%baz\bar\foo\biz.asmx
```

It is my desire to insert `App_Code` in the path of `.asmx` files like:

```
$FOO%foo\bar\App_code\biz.asmx
%FOO%foo\bar\biz.cs
%FOO%baz\bar\foo\App_Code\biz.asmx
```

Though I'm on a windows box I have gnuwin32, which gives me sed/awk/grep and other fancy stuff.

I'm not wedded to a particular solution, but am interested in the sed/awk route for my on enlightenment

I have tried:
`sed "s/\\([:alnum:]*)\.asmx/App_Code\/{1}/"`
which I had thought would capture any alphanumeric characters after a path separator (filename) that are followed by `.asmx`, and then replace it with `App_Code{contents of group}.
Something is off as it never finds what I want.  I'm strugging with the docs and examples, advice and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: recall that '*' in a reg exper means ZERO or more of the preceding exprer (in your case [:alnum:]). To have match at least one of your exper, you need to duplicate like `[:alnum:][:alnum:]*` to garantee matching at least one `[:alnum:]`. I'm pretty sure this doesn't solve your problem, but as you are interested 'for my enligthenment`, I'm happy to make that clarification for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting on Windows is a pain so put the following script into a file called `appcode.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\\"
}
$NF~/[.]asmx/{
    $NF = "App_code" OFS $NF
}
{
    print
}
```

And run like:

```
$ awk -f appcode.awk file
$FOO%foo\bar\App_code\biz.asmx
%FOO%foo\bar\biz.cs
%FOO%baz\bar\foo\App_code\biz.asmx
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\\ '/\.asmx/ {$NF="App_Code\\"$NF}1' OFS=\\ file
$FOO%foo\bar\App_Code\biz.asmx
%FOO%foo\bar\biz.cs
%FOO%baz\bar\foo\App_Code\biz.asmx
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\\\w+\.asmx)/\\App_Code\1/' files.txt
```

Output:

```
$FOO%foo\bar\App_Code\biz.asmx
%FOO%foo\bar\biz.cs
%FOO%baz\bar\foo\App_Code\biz.asmx
```

**EDIT**

As suggested in by [sudo_O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066031/sudo-o), capture group can be dropped and `&` can be used in the same command.

```
sed -r 's/\\\w+\.asmx/\\App_Code&/' files.txt
```